# Pytorch dataset RAM leakage

Tags: pytorch, memory-leaks, ram, pytorch-dataloader

There is a problem with a RAM leak, nothing leaks on the GPU. I have minimally shortened the code so that anyone can run it. I'll attach it below. Moreover, if you set shuffle = True, then the leak occurs much faster. Apparently, it is file_paths that is flowing, but it is unclear why. What could be the problem?

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torch

class MemLeakDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_paths = [(f"fake_file_path_{i}", i) for i in range(10_000_000)]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.file_paths)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        label = self.file_paths[idx][1]
        image = []

        return image, label


if __name__ == "__main__":
    train_dataset = MemLeakDataset()

    train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=256,
                                                   shuffle=False,
                                                   drop_last=False,
                                                   num_workers=10)

    count = 0

    for _ in train_dataloader:
        count += 1
        print(count)
```